# ASP .NET Core MapSpaFallbackRoute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, single-page-application

I'm trying to make SPA app using React as frontend and C# as backend.

I want to be able to navigate `/register` or `/register/conf` pages, so I'm using `MapSpaFallbackRoute()` in the next way:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", 
                   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```

But this example is not working. When I try to refresh or input directly `/register` page it sends me 404. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If anybody is interested, the answer was done at russian stackoverflow: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/912125/186973